# WebViewClient history wrong on HoneyComb

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebViewClient in an Activity in which I override the onKeyDown method like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    } else {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works like a charm on my phone as well as the emulators I tested on including a 3.0 emulator.

Weird thing is that on a 3.1 emulator as well as on my Xoom tablet (3.0.1) it does NOT work.  It seems that webView.canGoBack() always returns true on these platforms.

Questions:

Has anybody else found similar behaviour?

Do you have a workaround/hack that allows me to make the backbutton work to navigate in the web view history as well as ultimately out of the activity if required?

Update: I have since then change the app to use fragments with the compatbility library so I am now using this:

```
 webView.setOnKeyListener(
            new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        redirectHelper.finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

where redirect helper basically is a wrapper for proper finishing of an activity or removing a fragment from the stack. Still has the same issue though..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this without issues on 3.1 and Galaxy Tab 10.1.  Haven't tried onKeyDown method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if( webView.canGoBack() ) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have since moved to fragments and therefore can not test this anymore. From what I can tell though this is equivalent to what it is.